confirm not working on iOS after using native "back" (vue3, vue-router)
In my app the confirm dialog is broken on iOS after using the native "back" button. My app uses vue3 with vue-router. When just using the RouterLink elements to navigate the page, everything works fine
I created this minimal example with two pages, a main page and a about page where the result of a confirm dialog is shown: https://codesandbox.io
On edge everthing works fine. On ios i can naviate with the links without any problem and the confirm is requested every time. Once i used the safari back button, the confirm dialog is not requested again and always displaying false until i refresh the page.
